# WazirX API wrapper library

Tags: python, bots, cryptocurrency

I am new to using APIs and was trying to build a trading bot in python using WazirX exchange's REST API. I am unable to understand how to make API calls using their [documentation](https://docs.wazirx.com/#public-rest-api-for-wazirx) (Also, is this an example of a good API documentation or of a bad one?). Can anyone point to any python wrapper libraries through which I can execute trades using an API key and secret? I tried searching a lot but couldn't find any Github repository using their API to **execute trades** (I have seen some using the public endpoints only).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check if this helps. Link - https://github.com/arnabm14/WazirX_Crypto_Trading_Bot

Answer (score 0):

Wazirx itself has provided Ruby and Python connectors
There are also 3rd party libraries available which can be used.
https://docs.wazirx.com/#api-third-party-integrations